# maven-jetty-plugin can't bind address under linux

Tags: windows, linux, maven, jetty

I have added a maven-jetty plugin to my pom as follows:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <host>${jetty.host}</host>
                        <port>${jetty.port}</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>30000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopPort>${jetty.stop.port}</stopPort>
                <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                <contextPath>${jetty.contextpath}</contextPath>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This works fine under windows 7 but if I try to execute it under Linux (SuSE) it always fails with address already in use.

I tried localhost and 127.0.0.1 as jetty.host and a few numbers as ports. 
I checked the ports on the linux system and they are all not in used by other services.

I use maven 3.0.3 and JDK 1.6_29 on both systems.

Any ideas?

Comment: User permissions maybe? Also, what port numbers have you been using? I know Linux reserves the first 1000 ports, but I'd guess you've probably been using things like 8080, 8180 anyway.

Comment: I did the run with sudo so permissions should be no problem? I tested ports like 3333, 3344, 8888, 8080, 8181, 8282,9080... all the same effect.

Comment: The permissions are not the problem, because the ports are above 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the STOP port I missed to check!

Answer (score 0):

You can check which process has opened a port:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/

With

```
netstat -tulpn
```

You'll see the corresponding processes on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

try a different port with the following command

mvn -Djetty.port=7000 jetty:run